# Почему в мобильной версии белые отступы по бокам?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В версии для экранов 320px если открывать с телефона, то почему-то по бокам экрана белые отступы, что естественно быть не должно.
В чем здесь может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

У вас же в стилях прописано:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px)
.bestsellers-main>div {
    display: block;
    width: 290px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Ширина экрана 320px

Comment: У вас внутри блока изображение, для которого тоже задано     width: 290px !important;

Comment: Вы уверены, что ширина окна, на котором вы смотрите сайт, 320px?

Comment: Если вы хотите действительно адаптивный сайт, то вы должны верстать в процентном соотношении, а не устанавливать везде фиксированный размер, если только этого действительно не требуется.  Пропишите новые правила для блоков, для ширины экрана меньше 600px, ширина блоков пускай будет 100%

Comment: Vitaliy это все бисер перед нежеланием посмотреть стили скаченного шаблончика.

Answer (score 0):

Используй удаленную отладку https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging и всё тайное стайнет явным. Вообще Remote Debugging это неотъемлемая часть при разработке под мобильные устройства.